# How data loss and data sequence is managed in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

As in kafka offset is used to manage the sequence of data that needed to be transfer to consumer, how this type of management is done in RabbitMQ to manage the data sequence to prevent data loss.

Comment: Have you read any rabbitmq docs?

Answer (score 2):

RabbitMQ consumers do not maintain a client side offset like Kafka consumers must. Kafka stores all messages for a configured time period and clients manage their own offsets meaning that different clients can consume messages from different offsets within the queue. This means that different Kafka consumers are not competing consumers unless they coordinate and share their offset.

RabbitMQ is very different. Messages are stored until they get sent to a consumer and then acknowledged or they expire. If there are multiple consumers for one queue then they are competing consumers and one message can only be consumed by one of the many consumers.

RabbitMQ has the concept of a delivery tag which is a monotonically incrementing number that increments per message delivered over a channel. It has no global meaning, it has the scope of a single channel and so is not shared between consumers on different servers, processes. Consumers only need to track this number for message acknowledgement purposes, it is RabbitMQ that is responsible for choosing which message is delivered to which consumer.